# Counting unique dates in multiple date ranges in a row

Tags: excel, vba, date, count, formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple start and end dates in separate columns. I need to calculate the number of total unique days in these date ranges.

All "solutions" to my problem I have founds have all start dates in one column, and all end dates in a different column. I have all the data in one row.

Example:

- Start date 1 in E23. Value = **2019-01-01**
- End date 1 in F23. Value = **2019-01-03**
- Start date 2 in I23. Value = **2019-02-01**
- End date 2 in J23. Value = **2019-02-03**
- Start date 3 in M23. Value = **2019-01-02**
- End date 3 in N23. Value = **2019-01-03**
- (... multiple columns continue like this)

**The sum I am looking for in the example above is 6**, as start/end date 3 should be included in the start/end date 1.

Once I have tackled this problem, I need to just include results within a certain year. I will deal with that later.

---

Edit. I modified the solution below to the current code:

```
Function UniqueDayCount(rYear As Date, rCol As Integer) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rAllDates As Range
    Dim rDateGroup As Range
    Dim hUnqDates As Object
    Dim dtStart As Date
    Dim dtEnd As Date
    Dim dtTemp As Date

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rAllDates = Intersect(ws.Rows(rCol), ws.Range("E:F,I:J,M:N,Q:R,U:V,Y:Z,AC:AD,AG:AH,AK:AL,AO:AP,AS:AT,AW:AX,BA:BB,BE:BF"))
    Set hUnqDates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rDateGroup In rAllDates.Areas
        dtStart = Int(rDateGroup.Cells(1, 1).Value2)
        dtEnd = Int(rDateGroup.Cells(rDateGroup.Rows.Count, rDateGroup.Columns.Count).Value2)
        For dtTemp = dtStart To dtEnd
            If Year(dtTemp) = rYear Then
                If Not hUnqDates.Exists(dtTemp) Then hUnqDates.Add dtTemp, dtTemp
            End If
        Next dtTemp
    Next rDateGroup

    UniqueDayCount = hUnqDates.Count

End Function
```

I called it using the following formula: =UniqueDayCount(2019, ROW())

Comment: Can you sort the data by start date?

Comment: In the code you mean? I cannot sort the document, as the fields are in a pretty rigid and large spreadsheet.

Comment: I doubt this will be possible with the current data setup using formula.  It will probably require VBA.

Comment: I am happy to do it in VBA, however I have no clue how to do it. The one code that I have that works only works for data that is located in two columns - not a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rAllDates As Range
    Dim rDateGroup As Range
    Dim hUnqDates As Object
    Dim dtStart As Date
    Dim dtEnd As Date
    Dim dtTemp As Date

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rAllDates = Intersect(ws.Rows(23), ws.Range("E:F,I:J,M:N"))
    Set hUnqDates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rDateGroup In rAllDates.Areas
        dtStart = Int(rDateGroup.Cells(1, 1).Value2)
        dtEnd = Int(rDateGroup.Cells(rDateGroup.Rows.Count, rDateGroup.Columns.Count).Value2)
        For dtTemp = dtStart To dtEnd
            If Year(dtTemp) = 2019 Then
                If Not hUnqDates.Exists(dtTemp) Then hUnqDates.Add dtTemp, dtTemp
            End If
        Next dtTemp
    Next rDateGroup

    MsgBox hUnqDates.Count

End Sub
```

To use it as a worksheet function:

```
Function UniqueDayCount(ByVal arg_lYear As Long, ByVal arg_lRow As Long) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rAllDates As Range
    Dim rDateGroup As Range
    Dim hUnqDates As Object
    Dim dtStart As Date
    Dim dtEnd As Date
    Dim dtTemp As Date

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rAllDates = Intersect(ws.Rows(arg_lRow), ws.Range("E:F,I:J,M:N,Q:R,U:V,Y:Z,AC:AD,AG:AH,AK:AL,AO:AP,AS:AT,AW:AX,BA:BB,BE:BF"))
    Set hUnqDates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rDateGroup In rAllDates.Areas
        If IsNumeric(Int(rDateGroup.Cells(1, 1).Value2)) _
        And IsNumeric(Int(rDateGroup.Cells(rDateGroup.Rows.Count, rDateGroup.Columns.Count).Value2)) Then
            dtStart = Int(rDateGroup.Cells(1, 1).Value2)
            dtEnd = Int(rDateGroup.Cells(rDateGroup.Rows.Count, rDateGroup.Columns.Count).Value2)
            For dtTemp = dtStart To dtEnd
                If Year(dtTemp) = arg_lYear Then
                    If Not hUnqDates.Exists(dtTemp) Then hUnqDates.Add dtTemp, dtTemp
                End If
            Next dtTemp
        End If
    Next rDateGroup

    UniqueDayCount = hUnqDates.Count

End Function
```

Comment: So, I added more columns in the ws.Range. ws.Range("E:F,I:J,M:N,Q:R,U:V,Y:Z,AC:AD,AG:AH,AK:AL,AO:AP,AS:AT,AW:AX,BA:BB,BE:BF")) ... this produced a #VALUE error in Excel. Was there a limit to how many columns I could count?

Comment: @Kenneth ?? You can easily have that many columns in a Range object.  What I've provided wouldn't give a #VALUE error because that's the result of a formula, and this is a VBA Subroutine.  Did you modify it?  If so, can you please edit your question to show what you changed it to?

Comment: Yes. Please see above.

Comment: It appears the #VALUE error comes up if the cells are not either blank or contain a date. I use a formula to calculate the End date based on what is in the Start date. If the start date is blank, I suppose the value that comes out of the end-date formula screws up the function... the code in place is this: =IF(ISBLANK(AW23),"",AW23+AY$5+((AY$5/7)*2))

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code. I just need to make some changes to my formula to output "0" instead of "" in case there is no start date. It does not look as clean, but I can hide that with some conditional formatting.